# JDBC with Microsoft Access - The query return no rows when i use a date in the where clause

Tags: date, ms-access, jdbc

here is the code i execute...

```
dc.rs = dc.st.executeQuery("select count(*) from Accounts where date_join = CDATE(25-11-2012)");
```

It returns 0 rows even though I have 3 accounts in database that will match this. 
The format i use when i insert date is

```
CDATE(day-month-year)
```

I tried also this format, but still returns nothing..

```
CDATE('25-November-2012')
```

I also use that format when i search using dates. But i can't understand why it returns no rows.

i get this error when I try to use the getDate(1) after I query that..

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Restricted data type attribute violation on column number 1 (Expr1000)
```

Is there any wrong with my where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the where clause to **data_join = CDATE('25-11-2012')**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but It still returns 0 rows.

Comment: can you please tell me how is the date stored in your access DB in which format.Is it mm-dd-yyyy.

Comment: try this one CDATE('11-25-2012')

Comment: Thank you sir, all of your suggestions actually works... it just didn't work before because i have some problem in my code.. . :)